# Программная загрузка файлов на dropmefiles

Tags: php, java, html, 1с

Работаю с 1С. 1С может на клиенте открывать сайты, как браузер в поле HTML, или же общаться на прямую HTTP-запросами на сервере.
В опере через Network нашел список запросов, которые выполняет браузер, для того чтобы загрузить файл на сайт dropmefiles.com.
Написал логику запросов, но споткнулся на отправке запроса с заголовком:
session-id: 223492_o_1f6hjc8221cmf1pev1tv9jm1c82b
Первую часть "223492" я получил в предыдущем запросе в теле ответа.
А вот "_o_1f6hjc8221cmf1pev1tv9jm1c82b" не понятно как получена. Предполагаю это делается клиентскими скриптами.
Возможно есть технология, как я смогу получить это значение в контексте сервера?
В крайнем случае можно сэмулировать загрузку страницы на клиенте, но в теле страницы, тоже не смог найти этого.
Что тут можно сделать?
Написал разработчикам на почту, пока молчат, а АПИ на сайте нет.

Comment: Ответ разработчиков:
К сожалению, предоставить Вам API  не имеем возможности. Сам сервис работает только в web варианте и рассчитан на его использование только через браузер. Работа web сервиса предоставляется «как есть» и оказать консультацию по иным способам работы сервиса мы Вам не сможем, так как иная работа сервиса не подразумевается.

Comment: Никто не решал подобные вопросы?

Comment: А зачем вам именно DropMeFiles? Есть же достаточно сервисов с API

Comment: Этот первый нагуглился и у него файл удаляется сам. Вот захотел его использовать.
Плюс подкачать скилы работы с HTTP-запросами. Парсинг куков ранее делал.
Сейчас научиться бы session-id генерировать и дело в шляпе!
Хотя в теории я могу просто прибавить 1 символ (несколько) к ИД кнопки, она имеет такую текстовую форму как просит отправить заголовком запрос.

Comment: Хотя возможно вы правы, проще использовать хостинг с АПИ первый который открылся: https://ru.files.fm/api

Comment: Уже написал пару запросов, ссылка на загруженный файл получена. Правда функционал на удаление файлов и отправку на почту не нашел. Дефолтом там 60 дней стоит, многовато...